GNUCash checking account register not displaying decimals
GNUCash version 5.5
I am unable to consistently display the decimal in the checking account register. The Increase & Decrease columns don't display the decimals when there is no cents. The Balance column doesn't display the cents decimal at all.
I've searched the Help doc and elsewhere. It's not addressed. I'm unable to find a setting that would correct this. See screen print.


It sounds like a bug in GNUCash. Have you tried updating to GNUCash 5.6? Also consider reporting a bug at https://bugs.gnucash.org/

Pure guess, but check which currency it's set for...

SOLVED:  This issue was resolved when I found Accounts>>CHECKING>>[Right click]Edit Accounts>>Smallest fraction
When this is set to "1/100" the problem was resolved. Can this be made more intuitive by changing the title slightly to "Smallest fraction (decimal)"?

Whether that would be an improvement is a matter of opinion. Whether the change can be made is out of our scope; take that up with the program's maintainers. And please don't ask questions in Answers; if you have an additional question we *can" answer, either edit it into your original Question or (usually better) start a new Question.
